# 'Though 'company with 'So '

Tags: phrase-usage

I read a sentence from  “Principles.” Dalio, Ray.

> All successful people operate by principles that help them be successful, though what they choose to be successful at varies enormously, so their principles vary.

I understand the meaning like

> All successful people operate by principles that help them be successful.Their principles vary, because what they choose to be successful at varies enormously.

The author's sentence emphasize 'so their principles vary.'
'Nevertheless, is it a good grammar practice to apply 'though' and 'so' that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would explain the meaning better:

> All successful people operate by principles that help them be successful. **However**, what they choose to be successful at varies enormously. **Therefore**, their principles vary.

*Though* introduces an idea that opposes or qualifies (reduces the scope of) the previous idea. *So* introduces a conclusion that may be drawn from the previous ideas.

Here's a simpler example of the idea:

> It was cold yesterday, though I've been in much colder weather, so I wasn't uncomfortable.